# Is there a scriptable tool to apply instagram-like effects?

Tags: image, image-processing, instagram

I'm making a script that is downloading CC pictures from the internet.
Unfortunatly, i would like to apply them some effect.

Do you know any tool that could provide that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org) is scriptable. It includes some filters built in, and you can build many more sorts of filters by providing overlay and mask images, as well as custom pixel processing functions.